# How to disable secure pages on a local server?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've just moved a Drupal to my localserver and I forgot to disable Secure Pages.

Now I cannot access admin pages, because the site switches to HTTPS.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the module directly via the database. Just go into the `system` table, look for your module under the `name` column, and set the `status` field to zero.

Comment: @Patrick: no.  Some hooks may be called when certain modules are disabled that clean up or do other things, so only do this when you cannot disable them normally.

Comment: @Patrick: It happens to be safe for this particular module. But, hook_disable() gets called when a module is disabled normally through the admin interface, so be sure to inspect the module for hook_disable before doing it like this.

Comment: I have a similar issue -- i changed config for drupal to force SSL, but then remembered the server isn't configured. I don't feel like generating a self-signed or getting a cert and setting that up right now, so anyone know how disable this -- either in DB or Config file -- other than what's been suggested (which doesn't work)?

Comment: @Kasapo: If you've followed the instructions above, then securepages is definitely disabled. You might have another issue at hand (something on your Apache config maybe?). You should post a new question so that folks can help.

Comment: I realize this is tagged drupal6, but I have drupal7 and I think that the "securepages" module existed in 6 but may have been moved to core in 7?? As far as I know, I don't have a standalone securepages module. 
However I am using the LDAP module, and it appears the setting was actually in there. Luckily I have a multisite installation and while I can't log in to one site, I found I was still logged in as admin on the other site, so I was able to get to settings and turn it off.  Thanks for the help! I bet there's a setting in the `variable` table for LDAP stuff to turn it off too...

Answer (score 21):

In your settings.php file:

`$conf['securepages_enable'] = FALSE;`

This will override the database setting.

In your `sites/example.com/settings.php`, leave this line out, and then it will use whatever value is in the database.

Comment: for some reason in IE10 the https redirect was cached in the browser!  this solution worked for me, but IE10 wouldn't give up the redirect until I cleared IE's browser cache...

Comment: Any idea for newer versions of drupal? neither `$conf['securepages_enable']` nor `$conf['https']` seem to do anything (and I did clear cache in drupal, browser and restarted webserver to make sure it was reading config)

Comment: for future reference -- it was indeed another module (the LDAP module) controlling the HTTPS. I don't think i'm even using securepages.

Comment: Perfect solution. This could be the ACCEPTED ans.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using drush, you can keep the Secure Pages module enabled and just turn off the checkbox in the module's own config like:

```
drush vset securepages_enable 0
```

This will stop the redirect.

you can also change the URLs if you want, as follows, but the above is usually enough.

```
drush vset securepages_basepath http://nominet.dev
drush vset securepages_basepath_ssl http://nominet.dev
```

I'm running Drupal 7 btw, so YMMV, but seems to be a simple drush based solution following on from the above answer.

Answer (score 5):

The way I've done it without disabling the module is to use SQL to change the variable setting. First backup your database (in case you put a semicolon in the wrong place; scratch that, **always** back up your database before making changes on the command line) and then run the following SQL on your database:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name = 'securepages_enable';
```

Then:

```
DELETE FROM cache;
DELETE FROM cache_page;
```

You need those two lines in order to clear the cache, otherwise the variable might stick around for a while.

Comment: +1 I feel safer disabling a variable setting to turn off a feature rather than disabling a module through the db because of reasons listed above.

Comment: Since we live in the Drush era now, `drush -l yoursite.tld vset securepages_enable 0` should do the trick. `drush -l yoursite.tld cc all` just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Drush installed:

```
drush dis -y securepages
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and has been answered a few times, but there's another option that hasn't been suggested yet.

You could disable it completely:

```
// Disable SecurePages completely.
$conf['securepages_enable'] = FALSE;
```

and alter settings.php to enforce HTTPS depending on some context, e.g.:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['environment'] && $_SERVER['environment'] == 'staging')) {
  $conf['securepages_basepath'] = 'http://staging.example.com';
  $conf['securepages_basepath_ssl'] = 'https://staging.example.com';
} else if (isset($_SERVER['environment'] && $_SERVER['environment'] == 'production')) {
  $conf['securepages_basepath'] = 'http://www.example.com';
  $conf['securepages_basepath_ssl'] = 'https://www.example.com';
} else {
  // We're on dev or some other server instance where SSL isn't needed.
  $conf['securepages_enable'] = FALSE;
}
```

This is just an example, but it's been a helpful way for us to manage sites that exist on a dev server, a QA server, and a production server, where we want to track settings.php changes in version control without having to change things in each environment.